# Solving an elliptic superlinear problem using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

[image]

I'm trying to solve the above differential equation using the shooting method.  When i set `Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 1}` i get a solution, but it is equal to zero. I need a solution that is different of zero. When i increase the value of `z'[0]`, say to `z'[0]=1000` Mathematica stay running for a long time and i get no solution. How can i solve this?

Here is the code:

```
n = 3.;
xf = 10000.;
s = NDSolve[
   {
    -z''[t] == (1 + (n - 2) t)^(1/(2 - n) (2 (n - 1) + 0.001)) z[
        t]^2 (Sin[z[t]+2])
    , z[0] == 0, z'[xf] == 0}, z, {t, 0, xf},
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 1}
     }
   ] // Chop
Plot[Evaluate[z[t] /. s], {t, 0., 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem appears to satisfy the boundary condition `z'[t] == 0` at large `t` only for `z[t] == 0`, as can be seen from.

```
s = ParametricNDSolve[{-z''[t] == (1 + (n - 2) t)^(1/(2 - n) (2 (n - 1) + 10^-3))
    z[t]^2 (Sin[z[t] + 2]), z[0] == 0, z'[0] == sl}, {z, z'}, {t, 0, xf}, {sl}]
Plot[Table[Evaluate[z'[n][t] /. s],{n, -1, 1, 1/4}], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

or

```
Plot[z'[sl][100] /. s, {sl, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"z'[0]", "z'[100}"}]
```

[image]

Comment: how did you got the first graphic?

Comment: `ParametricNDSolve` provides solutions to differential  equations for various parameters, in this case `z'[0]`.  The first graphic displays solutions for `z'[0]` with values given by `Range[-1, 1, 1/4]`,

Comment: `n = 3.;
p = 2.;
xf = 1000000.;
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-z''[
      t] == (1 + (n - 2) t)^(1/(2 - n) (2 (n - 1) + 10^-5)) z[
       t]^2 Sin[z[t] + 2] , z[0] == 0, z'[xf] == bc2}, 
  z'[xf], {t, 0, xf}, bc2]` do you know why after solving this equation the following plot take so long? `Plot[s[bc2], {bc2, 0, 2.1}]`

Comment: `ParametricNDSolve` does not actually solve the ODE until the parameter `bc2` is specified.  `Plot` probably requires several tens of solutions, and each is slow, because `xf` is very large.